# Receive the word cluster based on words and not for every row

Tags: r, quanteda

I try to use this approach

```
library(quanteda)

dataset1 <- data.frame( anumber = c(1,2,3), text = c("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.","It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum", "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source."))

myDfm <- dataset1 %>%
corpus() %>%
tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
dfm()%>%                         


   dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 1)
        
tstat_dist <- textstat_simil(myDfm, method = "cosine")

# hiarchical clustering the distance object
pres_cluster <- hclust(as.dist(tstat_dist))
# label with document names
pres_cluster$labels <- docnames(myDfm)
# plot as a dendrogram
plot(pres_cluster, xlab = "", sub = "", main = "Cosine Distance on Token Frequency")
```

to extract word cluster for words but in the final plot I receive the name of document which is every row I have. Is it possible to make any changes to receive the words of text and not the document names in the cluster?

I would expect to see this words:

```
textstat_frequency(myDfm, n = 5)
```

> ```
>   feature frequency rank docfreq group
> 1     the        10    1       3   all
> 2      of         7    2       3   all
> 3   lorem         6    3       3   all
> 4   ipsum         6    3       3   all
> 5       a         5    5       2   all
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you need the `margin = "features"` argument in your computation of distance.  (And you can remove the labels assignment.)  So the last part of your code should be:

```
# compute the distance on features, not documents
tstat_dist <- textstat_simil(myDfm, method = "cosine", margin = "features")
# hiarchical clustering the distance object
pres_cluster <- hclust(as.dist(tstat_dist))
# plot as a dendrogram
plot(pres_cluster, xlab = "", sub = "", main = "Cosine Distance on Token Frequency")
```

**However** you should be computing a distance metric, not cosine similarity for computing a hierarchical clustering.

Comment: I would like to use as method for the distance metric the option of jaccard, however this method doesn't exist in this `stat_dist <- textstat_dist(myDfm, method = "jaccard")` Is there any different option?

Comment: I would like to use Jaccard’s coefficient similarity measure determine the association between phrases that occur close together

Comment: For clustering, you can transform the Jaccard similarity into a distance measure by subtracting it from 1.0, same with cosine.